# How can I find rows that have two columns that are the same, but one column differs?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with a bunch of differnt tables that are joined together to create the following table:

```
Col1   Col2    Col3           Col4
51     1       1101    2009-01-24 00:00:00.000
52     1       1101    2009-05-14 00:00:00.000
76     1       1101    2009-02-04 00:00:00.000
78     2       1101    2009-09-29 00:00:00.000
79     1       1101    2009-09-25 00:00:00.000
79     2       1101    2009-09-25 00:00:00.000
80     1       1101    2009-02-09 00:00:00.000
80     1       1101    2012-09-26 00:00:00.000
80     2       1101    2009-02-09 00:00:00.000
80     2       1101    2012-09-26 00:00:00.000
```

I basically want to get only the rows that are like 79 or 80 where there is at least two rows that are the same in Col1 and Col3 but Col2 is different.

I'm new to SQL so I don't know if this is simple or not, I'm hoping somebody can help.

Thanks

I'm hoping to only display the rows that have the same values in column 1 and 3 but differ in column 2, so for the instance above only display the rows for 79 and 80.

Comment: Please format you table in a human-readable way.

Comment: Could you show a desired result? I can't quite read from your description what you're expecting as a result, all rows or one for each group or...?

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't realize how terrible it looked initially.  Fixed now

Comment: So, would the result for '80' be two rows? as in 80 with 1 and 80 with 2 for col1/col2 ?

Comment: I'm not really picky with how the results are displayed, 80 could be displayed twice or once, doesn't bother me one way or the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a combination of `group by`, `having` and `count distinct` should return what you want

```
select col1, col3, count (distinct col2)
from yourtable
group by col1, col3
having count(distinct col2) >= 2
```

If you want to display complete set of data, join this result set to the original data source.

```
select t.* from yourtable t
    inner join
(
    select col1, col3
    from yourtable
    group by col1, col3
    having count(distinct col2) >= 2
) v
    on t.col1 = v.col1
    and t.col3 = v.col3
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest possible since you seem to only want the distinct Col1 values matching the criteria displayed should be;

```
SELECT DISTINCT Col1
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Col1,Col3
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Col2) > 1
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/69cca/3).